Temporary user profile is created for the user on Windows 11 following domain controller upgrade
I recently migrated from Windows Server 2012 to Windows Server 2022. To do this I added WS2022 to WS2012 and upgraded it as a domain controller so I had all the AD users in WS2022.
When a  user is logged in, it doesn't log him to his user folder that exists in C:\users instead it creates a TEMP folder and it connects the user to it.
An online suggestion to go to registry under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList, and delete the user without .bak and remove .bak from the user that has it, and also to set the state key in the profile of the user to 0.
I also gave all permission to the user folder and it still did not work.

When a user is logged in to their desktop?

Yes , when for example jhon@company.local logs to his computer and enter his desktop, he doesn't find his files, because he is in a user folder called TEMP, his files are on another folder C:\Jhon even though he logged using jhon@company.local

What does the eventlog say?
